# Is there a way to get OscillatorNode to produce a sound on an iOS device?

Tags: javascript, ios, html5-audio

I'm working on a [music web app](https://lshillman.github.io/anglo-piano/) that has a piano keyboard. When a user presses a piano key, I'm using OscillatorNode to play a brief tone corresponding to the key:

```
const audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

function playNote(note) {
    let oscillator;
    let freq = notes[note];
    console.debug(note + " (" + freq + " Hz)");
    oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator(); // create Oscillator node
    oscillator.type = wavetypeEl.val(); // triangle wave by default
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(freq, audioCtx.currentTime); // freq = value in hertz
    oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    oscillator.stop(audioCtx.currentTime + 0.5);
}

$('#keyboard button').on('click', (e) => {
        playNote(e.target.dataset.note);
});
```

This works on all the desktop and Android browsers I've tried, but iOS stubbornly refuses to play any sound. I see that I need a user interaction to "unlock" an AudioContext on iOS, but I would have thought calling `playNote()` from my click function would have done the trick.

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html), I should be able to use `noteOn()` on my oscillator object, instead of `oscillator.start()` the way I've got it in my example. But that doesn't seem to be a valid method.

I must be missing something simple here. Anybody know?

Comment: I ran your music web app in the XCode Simulator 14.0.1 with Safari and it works like it should. I'm hearing the notes when clicking the keyboard.

Comment: The Apple documentation you mention in your question is about the older `webkitAudioContext` interface, hence the `noteOn` which doesn't exist. The `AudioContext` interface has [very good support](https://caniuse.com/?search=AudioContext), so there might not be a need to use `webkitAudioContext`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I was using the simulator too, but apparently it's muted by default (though it plays html5 audio just fine). Massive facepalm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything seems to be working fine it could be that the device itself is on mute. For some reason (or for no reason at all) Safari doesn't play any sound coming from the Web Audio API when the device is muted. But it plays everything else.

There are some hacky ways to circumvent this bug which basically work by playing something with an audio element first before using the Web Audio API.

[unmute-ios-audio](https://github.com/feross/unmute-ios-audio) is for example a library which implements the hack mentioned above.

Comment: Well, I'll be. I was using a fresh install of the iOS simulator and had tested its ability to play audio by visiting YouTube, which worked, but uses a totally different method for playing audio. Apparently the simulator is muted by default. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone XS Max and the demo works on it producing sound as you have it right now... I've also read that for iOS the element needs both onClick handler and a style of {cursor: pointer} set to work properly.(as of a few years ago) seems like it's working though.